# Undefined index trying to uploading a picture

Tags: php, html

A.php

```
<form action="pic.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="pic">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

pic.php

```
print $_FILES; // Returns Array

if ($_FILES['pic']['name']){
    $pic_path = '/pictures/' . $_FILES['pic']['name'];
}
```

I'm trying to upload a picture along with other data, however I'm getting an error as it the index didn't exist... `undefined index: pic` and don't know why.

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" you missing this !!!!

Comment: @saurabhkamble same error.. xD

Comment: just print $_files in pic.php are you getting anything

Comment: @saurabhkamble yep, it returns `Array`

Comment: add it to your question and that enctype also

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the error is only coming if you did *not* upload a file, right?

You need to check if anything was uploaded first with `is_uploaded_file()`, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

EDIT: See here for a tutorial: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: it's the same, `if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['name']))` returns the same error